# "Desynonymize" php and php5

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms

[Due to this question,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59285/synonyms-mean-interchangeable-not-similar) I think it would be better to remove `php5` as synoym for `php`.

I proposed it as a synonym because I didn't know how the system really works. The community decided that it should be a synonym but the question I link to and other comments clearly show that this is not desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I deleted this synonym.

Comment: Can you also block new question being asked with the PHP5 tag?