# Can someone make php5 a synonym of the php tag?

Tags: support, status-declined, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms

These were desynonymized due to this question:

["Desynonymize" php and php5](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59308/desynonymize-php-and-php5)

Clearly there isn't support for undoing that for policy reasons, so I'll try a different argument:

PHP 5 is the current version of PHP, and has been for the past 7 years. In the abstract, policy-level world, maybe `php5` and `php` aren't synonyms. In actually curating SO content, they are.

If anyone were to go through the ~4000 posts tagged `php5` and retag to `php` those questions which are not about anything version specific, they'd be retagging 99% of them. In the other 1%, the `php5` tag doesn't add anything anyway, since PHP5 is the default PHP askers/answerers are talking about.

It's not like other languages where there is any significant number of people using a previous version and tagging with version numbers actually clarifies what you can use in your answer. Not tagging these questions as `php` is just throwing away value. It makes them less visible to SO users, and less likely to match Google/Bing search queries.

Optimally someone would come along and retag all those questions, but PHP users are so... special... that there are too many mistagged to clean up.

Comment: Well it doesn't make it harder, just use the tag `php*` and you will get everything php related. I don't find this pretty hard.

Comment: That is much harder, as it requires insider information. There is nothing to indicate to the average user during their use of the site that such a thing is possible. It also doesn't help when you click on tags to navigate to tag pages.

Comment: read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59285/synonyms-mean-interchangeable-not-similar , we have no tag hierarchy, the synonym you are suggesting makes no sense

Answer (score 5):

You've just repeated the same weak arguments that were thoroughly rebutted in numerous past discussions on the subject. What makes you think this time is going to be different?

Comment: They are just as strong in the previous posts, I don't understand why they were desynonymized in the first place. Other languages don't have this problem. We don't tag every c# question with a .NET version, every Java question with a JVM version... This question is going to be re-asked by people until something sane is done.

Comment: @Dan: You don't understand because you've done zero research. That question you link to is but one small piece of the puzzle. Try reviewing other linked and related questions.

Comment: I have done the research, I disagree with the accepted answer in the previous questions. The conclusion was "PHP != PHP5", which is silly and wrong. PHP = PHP5. It is the only major deployed version, the only supported version, the only version released in the past 7 years.

Comment: @Dan: PHP = PHP5 is silly and wrong, just as .NET == .NET 4 would be silly and wrong. Other languages DO have versioned tags and they DO get used. If you think the PHP 5 tag is being overused, that's a user education problem, not a synonymization problem.

Comment: @Dan: PHP has version-specific features and backwards-incompatible changes just like every other language. There is nothing special about it.