# Which moderator can help with creating a Tag Synonym?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can someone make php5 a synonym of the php tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76605/can-someone-make-php5-a-synonym-of-the-php-tag)

[I have reviewed Tag synonym [tag:php5] to [tag:php] now for quite some time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135800/147909). To the best knowledge I can say, for new questions, the [php5](/questions/tagged/php5) tag is not needed any longer and [php](/questions/tagged/php) should be used instead. That would help a lot for keeping PHP well present on the site.

However I have the following problem which makes me need some help:

> [image]

So any moderator can help making [php5](/questions/tagged/php5) a synonym of [php](/questions/tagged/php) so that new questions will have the [php](/questions/tagged/php) only, not [php5](/questions/tagged/php5) any longer?

Note: Users should still be able to properly tag their PHP version, like [php-5.1](/questions/tagged/php-5.1) or [php-5.2](/questions/tagged/php-5.2) for questions specific to older PHP versions.

Comment: Why would we want to synonymize [php] with [php5]?

Comment: Maybe I'm using the wrong words. I want that if a user enters a "PHP5" tag with her new question, that the tag is changed to "PHP" automatically. "PHP5" does not mean much as of today, normally PHP is meant. In cases not PHP generally is meant, a specific version like PHP 5.1 is meant. That's why.

Comment: Also the so said duplicate is not about concrete limitation that I can not handle this on my own because of these "version specific synonyms". Also I'm not sure if the suggested duplicate is actually about new questions. Having that synonym would help in maintaining the PHP tag on the site. Thank you for your support. Otherwise this is a lot of legwork for the active users taking care of this.

Comment: @Yannis: It's obvious they're now widely considered equivalent. Questions pertaining to historic versions can be tagged with [php4] at will. But gloryfing the syntactic differences introduced in php5 (people love to make a big deal out of the Javaish object syntax, I know) with a separate tag seems insensible to me too. -- Though can't be bothered to do any thorough scan, but the fear of misclassifying older posts from php4-intended [php] tags is less plausible nor reasoning for keeping the tag surplus.

Comment: I do not want to re-tag old posts. I want to prevent that users as of today just put PHP5 to their question (often next to PHP) just because they think: the more, the better.

Comment: I understand the problem of users using [php5] when they really mean [php] in general - I have to deal with [html5][css3] questions when they really are just general [html][css] questions. The problem with creating a synonym, though, is that the mapping works automatically for all posts, including old ones. The synonym is effectively hidden from view and the target is shown instead. Unfortunately, there isn't anything that can be done about that with the current tag synonym system.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: Thanks for the clarification I was not aware of that. Then this is not feasible with the synonym system indeed. Maybe this needs some additional pre-moderation tools ;) ^^ And yes I can understand that HTML5 and CSS3 is something similar. If I run over those cases I re-tag them as well.