# Would specialized version tags be useful?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow, tags

Now, there are questions that relate to a specific product `X`.

The answers to these questions are completely dependent on the version of the product used. A particular function does not exist in version `1`, but is there in version `2`. Additionally, it is a fact of life that an answer like "upgrade to version `2`" is sometimes not proper. Maybe the person asking the question cannot upgrade. Maybe the function does not exist in version `2` either, but the solution is different depending on version.

Additionally, without the version-specific information, a question that was originally correct may degrade into "incorrectness": most current users may use the latest version, and may down-vote answers that were correct in their time frame or even edit a question/answer to correspond to "current correctness."

The proposed specialized version tag would provide versatility for a given question. It implies a tree of potential answers depending on the searched version. It may even constrict the potential answers to only that version.

It will play a small part when a user searches for an appropriate answer or wants to ask a question.

In some cases, normal tags can be used: there are already tags like [c#-2.0](/questions/tagged/c%23-2.0), [c#-3.0](/questions/tagged/c%23-3.0) and [c#-4.0](/questions/tagged/c%23-4.0) (but where are [c#-3.5](/questions/tagged/c%23-3.5), or even [c#-1.1](/questions/tagged/c%23-1.1)?). But what happens when I have question that relates only to [nhibernate-2.0.1](/questions/tagged/nhibernate-2.0.1)? 
**Assuming that I have the reputation** to create a new tag, this tag is only important as 'meta': I want a way to communicate that I have a version constraint. There are no followers of [nhibernate-2.0.1](/questions/tagged/nhibernate-2.0.1), and it uses up one out of the five tag slots. Personally, I use the RSS tag-tracking feature for [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23); why should I miss [c#-x.x](/questions/tagged/c%23-x.x) questions? And am I not polluting the tag cloud by inserting an [x-y.z](/questions/tagged/x-y.z) tag?

I am posting this here because it's a system thing, though only a few sites in Stack Exchange would benefit from such a feature — although you could have different versions of the same turkey salad on [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/), I suppose.

So, is there any merit in my thinking? I could say some more things but I would also like some feedback. Maybe this discussion already took place in an earlier version of Stack Overflow and was down-voted into oblivion....

Comment: Note that 3.5 and 1.1 are not versions of C#, but of the .NET framework

Comment: There are many existing posts related to this one: [Could we make tags imply other tags?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2781/could-we-make-tags-imply-other-tags), [suggestion: tag inheritance (not the tag “inheritance”, but the concept of tag inheritance)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60570/), [Implicit tagging hierarchy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58073/), [Tag hierarchy absence - design reasons?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45377/), [A proposal for tag hierarchy on SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45438/)

Comment: interesting, i didn't consider this an implicit hierarchy tag system so i didn't put those words on the search. The downvote is weird though. I believe this is a valid question

Comment: Anyway it was declined sometime ago: [Another kind of tag hierarchy/relationship](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59309/)

Answer (score 0):

<del>In spite of my linkfest comment on the question itself, this feature request comes down to</del>

> <del>this tag is only important as 'meta':</del>

Meta-tags are not allowed, [as of August](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

Users with version constraints should simply mention them in the bodies of their questions.

EDIT:
After re-reading the question body — thanks @frisco — I see that I misunderstood the OP's request initially, so the first part of my original answer doesn't apply. I still think the second part is valid, though.

Comment: If you just read the manifest aginst Meta-tags it is clear we are not talking about the same thing. Meta-tags discouraged are meta information about the question, this time we are talking about meta information about the tag, C#-4.0 is crystal clear for everyone and not subjetive, it defines the question even better than C# but lacks the followers C# has.

Comment: @frisco, okay, I read the "manifesto" quite clearly, but I misunderstood what the OP of this question was suggesting. I'll edit that out. I stand by my last sentence, though; there's no need to pollute the tag system with this information.

Comment: @frisco that's the basic point. i follow c# in general, why should i have to follow every c# related tag in the universe?