# When is it appropriate to have minor version numbers for tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are some very specific tags like [ruby-1.9.2](/questions/tagged/ruby-1.9.2), for which there is already [ruby-1.9](/questions/tagged/ruby-1.9).

When is it appropriate to have minor version numbers for tags?

Also, would it make sense to automatically have these revisions pointing to the original tag? (I'm aware it's been asked before: [Would specialized version tags be useful?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78522/would-specialized-version-tags-be-useful))

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's appropriate to use tags when your question is specific to that revision. For example.

Your code works with ruby 1.9. But with 1.9.2 it behaves differently.

Or when you are a lazy copy/paste activist.

Comment: This. With Python, 2.x or 3.x is usually as specific as it is necessary to be, and questions often aren't even specific to 2.6 or 3.1 or whatever. There is no need to tag that specifically unless it actually matters for your question. Just mention the exact version in your question _somewhere_ just it case it's relevant and you don't know.

Comment: @agf: I agree. I would also advise contributing to the vendor's bug tracker in such situation as the implementation is probably bugged if minor versions start introducing major changes.

Answer (score 1):

I think for minor revisions, you can just note the revision specifics in the question and/or title.  There's no need for a tag for every revision.  Not many people would go searching by minor revision.

Note: By minor revision, I mean just that.  If there are substantial differences, then whether or not the developers used the third decimal place, there should probably be separate tags.

It will also depend on how much traffic a particular language gets, I know for certain we really don't need pre-.net VB tags with more than one digit.

Comment: ruby 1.9.0 vs 1.9.2 are very different - 1.9.0 had lots of bugs and quite a few missing features

Comment: I guess maybe we shouldn't just whether a version is minor by the third decimal then.  I'll throw a disclaimer in.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the the two language versions differ greatly, I see no reason why to have multiple tags. Just use one tag and the OP can state which version they are working with.

Comment: Even for versions that barely differ at all sometimes something breaks between two versions. Then they're relevant as tags, as someone might search for that exact version if they have the same problem.