# Question Clusters - what is the META guideline for consolidating similar questions?

Tags: support, answers, duplicate-answers

I would like to help others by consolidating *Solved* questions that are related to the same *Component*. Does the Stack Exchange platform have a policy for chaining together *Solved* questions?

I am most active on [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com), and occasionally my search returns:

- large number of *Solved* questions
- each *Solved* question is unique and relates to the same *Component*
- when reviewed as a group, all of the *solved* questions are aspects of the same problem
- applying one *solved*, results in the next problem, which can be solved by one of the other *solved* questions in the search results

A search example is [yaml.scanner.ScannerError [python]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=yaml.scanner.ScannerError%20%5Bpython%5D).

One alternative being considered is to create a new question. Indicate that it is a 'Solved Cluster' for *Component*, and then answer the question by providing a list of problem descriptions with link to original *Solved* question.

> *Component*: in this post the term is a generic reference to:
>
> - software code (such as function, method, class, procedure)
> - software topic (broadly accepted as having a specific scope)
>
> *Solved*: in this post the term means 'an answer' a popular answer or an answer accepted by question author

Comment: The search example points to Stack Overflow. It looks that this question belongs to [meta.so](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) rather than here, unless that you are looking to consolidate questions across the Stack Exchange network but there isn't a feature that allows.

Comment: What do you mean by "stackexchange.com question"? This is unclear because stackexchange.com is a "portal"... questions aren't posted directly to this domain, they are posted on specific sites.

Comment: You have two options: pick the best canonical and close all other question as duplicate of the canonical or you ask for a merge. Mods can do that but it often is done by asking a meta question first. If anything, adding another question is the least preferred if not right out wrong option. For your example search you would now have 24 problems. If you want to curate a list of common answers, consider adding them to a tag wiki (that nobody reads)

Comment: Hi [rene](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/158100/rene) thankyou. Post [comment 2022-10-09 05:29:22Z](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382733/question-clusters-what-is-the-meta-guideline-for-consolidating-similar-questio#comment1276536_382733) as answer so this can be marked solved.

Comment: What do "Solved(sic)" and "Component(sic)" mean? I had the idea the former is how SE labels questions with accepted answers, and that you have a problem with the word 'Solved', but what then is 'Component'?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Version labels for answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370640/version-labels-for-answers)

Comment: Is there something not up-to-your needs about the "related" list? (Found on every question page, right hand side on a big screen?)

Comment: Considering the changes done to the question, I think that it should be reopened. In the meantime, AFAIK there is no "Stack Exchange policy for chaining together Solved questions" because that is not part of the workings of the Stack Exchange model. Stack Exchange has tags, a search engine and filters as part of the core model. On Stack Overflow there are Collectives that among other features creates a "cluster" of questions based on tags. Collectives could be searched for answered questions.  In SO, something close to what you want to do is usually referred as "FAQ".

Comment: In this context, if you are interested in one of the tags included in a Collective, it might be interesting to explore "articles" that is another content type.

Answer (score 2):

We like to allow sites some freedom to operate in their own ways so if you want to create a canonical question and answer and then mark other questions as that questions duplicate then you should find out how the specific site you're proposing to do that one works by looking on its site specific meta.

Stack Overflow for instance does have a number of popular canonical questions with canonical answers that new questions with that issue are frequently duplicated to. It also has [guidance on canonical questions and answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291992/what-is-a-canonical-question-answer-and-what-is-their-purpose), some of which may well be specific to that specific site.

You should also search for existing canonical questions and answers before creating your own.

Comment: There are also hidden gems in tag wikis (though not that many). For example, the [Java one](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info) has an FAQ section.