# Version tag in addition to main tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

I find that questions related to database topics are frequently dependent on the RDBMS's engine and version.

So when (from reading the question) I can figure out the version, and I know (or suspect) that it is important I edit the question adding the version tag to the existent main tag, say [postgresql-8.4](/questions/tagged/postgresql-8.4) in addition to [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql).

Is it good practice?

Comment: I usually do this on SO, I guess it's a good practice.

Comment: Related post: [Would specialized version tags be useful?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78522/would-specialized-version-tags-be-useful?rq=1)

Comment: Quoting [Popular Demand](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/131713/popular-demand), ["Users with version constraints should simply mention them in the bodies of their questions"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/78535/166025)

Comment: I certainly think so; unless you actually do have 5 other legitimately useful tags (usually 2 non-version tags is a stretch, like C++ and "time") and it helps sort out the problem of "duplicates" when previous questions for previous versions are now out of date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Version tags should be added when the question is specific for a version, and not for all the versions.

For example, if I ask a question about the `user_save()` function defined in Drupal 7, I should probably add [drupal-7](/questions/tagged/drupal-7) because the function has been changed in Drupal 7, and its parameters are different from the same function defined in Drupal 6. If I ask a question about the `if` control statement in PHP, I should not use a version tag, as the `if` statement is defined in all the PHP versions, and there aren't changes in any of the PHP versions.

Using the generic tag, and the version tag is fine, as it exposes the questions to more users.