# Rolling back an edit can create a "new tag" that had been synonymized in the interim

Tags: bug, tags, tag-synonyms, rollbacks

In December 2012, [php5](/questions/tagged/php5) was [synonymized](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160216/135887) with [php](/questions/tagged/php).  This means that anyone trying to tag their question [php5](/questions/tagged/php5) gets [php](/questions/tagged/php) instead.

Earlier today, [revision 5 to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6000996/revisions) rolled back a set of edits that ended up removing [php5](/questions/tagged/php5) as part of the pre-synonym purge.

As a result, the "new" [php5](/questions/tagged/php5) appeared in the [10k tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools) new tag list:

[image: A screenshot of the 10k tools showing the "new" tag.]

It also appears on the list of tags on the [Tags tab when sorted by newest](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new):

[image: A screenshot of the Tags tab demonstrating the presence of the "new" tag]

I've since purged the heathen.  Er.  Tag.

How is this possible?  Shouldn't the system have detected that the tag has been synonymized and redirected as appropriate?  Or does the synonym retag redirect magic happen only when invoking the actual editor?  Or is the rollback mechanism just that *brutal*?

Comment: [related to this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212557/diamond-moderator-rollbacks-can-resurrect-blacklisted-tags), we're looking into it.