# Diamond moderator rollbacks can resurrect blacklisted tags

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, rollbacks, blocked-tags

[Example revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5491879/revisions).

A diamond moderator rolled back a question to a state where it had [homework](/questions/tagged/homework).  This effectively recreated the tag, despite it being blacklisted.

This should not happen, and is [not the only tag-related rollback bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179510/135887).

Comment: It's back from the grave! D:

Comment: If there was ever a time to push *all the red buttons*...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***OH NO QUICK GET EVERYTHING OF VALUE AND GET OUT BEFORE THE PLACE BUR...***

It's still blacklisted, so it can't get back in through the efforts of a human being typing it; the most annoying thing that could happen is a post becomes edit-blocked until someone removes the blacklisted tag.

This shouldn't have happened, I distinctly remember Shog9 taking an axe to homework just like I recently did to logic:

[image: And I totally did it, too]

But, that obviously doesn't scope previous revisions. I'm going to look into it. It's not uncommon for us to blacklist a tag just to stop the influx while communities go to work removing it *carefully*, which can be an edit blocker (we're not fond of that, but that makes fixing this sort of weird).

Unceremoniously and silently dropping a blacklisted tag from a question during a rollback makes the most sense, but I need to think about that and find out just how possible that might be. [Homework synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/homework/synonyms) become quite interesting too, in the context of the other bug that you linked.

In the mean time ...

[image: Remain calm]

... and stay tuned.

Comment: +1 for carrying on with my burninate request. :-)

Comment: I think it was your destruction of logic that caused this to happen.

Comment: Is that really the message you guys see when you burninate? Because that's damn awesome.

Comment: Wait, wait, wait.  Are you saying that the dev tools say "damn sure" *and* that they're presented in Times New Roman?

Comment: It's... my fault. D: Tim was right all along!

Comment: I... probably shouldn't have said that...

Comment: @Charles the tag burninator is dev only. And it was at Jamal's request that I destroyed logic, so blame him.

Comment: Hey!  It was just on Code Review!  Just one universe (or galaxy)!

Comment: I... clicked that button. Just in... just in case it worked.