# Undeleting a question can also undelete blacklisted tags

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, blocked-tags

The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9754534/168868) and [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9754534/revisions).

When the question was deleted, we hadn't yet blacklisted [homework](/questions/tagged/homework).  Once the question was undeleted, the system recreated it.  It probably shouldn't do that.

Probably related:

- [Diamond moderator rollbacks can resurrect blacklisted tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212558/135887)
- [Rolling back an edit can create a “new tag” that had been synonymized in the interim](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179510/135887)

Comment: It's back *again*?  Okay, now it's just trolling us...

Comment: The tag came back, the very next day.  The tag came back, we thought it was a goner...