# Tags with versions

Tags: feature-request, tags

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Tag hierarchy absence - design reasons?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45377/tag-hierarchy-absence-design-reasons)
>   [Another kind of tag hierarchy/relationship](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59309/another-kind-of-tag-hierarchy-relationship)

It is good to see in `ruby` tag either `ruby1.9` and `ruby1.8`. It shouldn't be synonymous but some kind of root tag, which includes all version tags.

It is not about ruby of course :) but about all tags.

I think adding such kind of nesting wlll be good.

Thx

**UPD**

actually I was talking about quite another thing: I want to see just versioning TAGS. As far as I am looking on `ruby` tag I want to see `ruby1.8` and `ruby1.9` and `ruby` and all other virsions tags! And `ruby-on-rails`  should include `ruby-on-rails-3` and `ruby-on-rails2` and so on. **IT IS NOT ABOUT HIERARCHY and tags nesting**. It is about just including all versions tag into main tag without version.

I think this topic should be reopened

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45377/tag-hierarchy-absence-design-reasons

Comment: I am talking about another feature

Answer (score 1):

I don't know ruby at all, but if it is mostly like any other language out there, if you can answer ruby-1.9 you can also answer ruby-1.8. There's also the problem of how to tag the question: if a question is not really specific to a particular version, which one you use? ruby-1.8? ruby-1.9? ruby-latest? ruby-all?
It seems to me that it would add a whole level of complexity without any added value.