# Break the [php4] -> [php] synonym

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

Please break the `[php4]` ➟ `[php]` synonym (as synonyms are meant to be [interchangeable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59285/synonyms-mean-interchangeable-not-similar)).

Comment: While we're at it, [php5 ➱ php](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info) already was at +2 again...

Comment: How is it that your comment has **three** upvotes, but php5 -> php is only down **one** from +2?

Comment: @Peter: I think there is some rep requirement for voting on synonyms

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Done, I'm seriously considering adding a black list of synonyms so this does not happen over and over again (please create a feature request for this)

Comment: Feature request opened: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62379/implement-tag-synonym-black-list