# Add a tag-synonym black-list

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

Some bad synonyms like [phpX → php](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62326/break-the-php4-php-synonym) repeatedly get proposed again and even upvoted and active.

As long as the users are not sufficiently aware of the meaning of synonyms, a black list would help. This would ideally be pattern-based to allow for blocking of `[phpN]→[php]` or `[javaN]→[java]`, `[javaN.N]→[java]` etc.

Comment: personally I want this, but lets wait for the new "restricted voting" rules to bake for a while first