# Cleanup ruby-on-rails synonyms

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms

Currently, we have:

```
ruby-on-rails  × 26940   <-  ruby-on-rails2  × 4      Simone Carletti (proposed)
ruby-on-rails3 × 465     <-  ruby-on-rails-3 × 2212   Helen 
ruby-on-rails-3-beta     <-  ruby-on-rails3beta       Bill the Lizard♦ 
ruby-on-rails3 × 465     <-  ruby-on-rails-3-beta     shingara
```

So we have:

- One beta being remapped to a non-beta, but one beta being remapped to a beta
- Two many-dashes being remapped to fewer-dashes, but one fewer-dashes being remapped to more dashes.

*(And one proposed throw-away-the-version-number.)*

Which of these are desirable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are desirable:

```
ruby-on-rails-3   <-  ruby-on-rails3    
ruby-on-rails-3-beta  <-  ruby-on-rails3beta
```

These are [people misunderstanding](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59285/synonyms-mean-interchangeable-not-similar) how the synonym functionality is meant to work:

```
ruby-on-rails  × 26940   <-  ruby-on-rails2  
ruby-on-rails3 × 465     <-  ruby-on-rails-3-beta
```

Comment: You may need to include a 20 point note along the lines of **"Not for hierarchical tags"**

Comment: So how come new questions tagged `[ruby-on-rails-3]` are still appearing?

Comment: @skaffman ... I just did a cleanup [ruby-on-rails-3] was more popular so I kept it ... I removed a bunch of weird synonyms as well ...

Comment: As a ruby dev, I'd prefer `ruby-on-rails` tag to follow the latest stable releases, which now is rails 3.0, soon to become 3.1. I feel the same about the `ruby` tag.